# Has anyone integrated Terracotta EHcache + WebSession with JBoss?

Tags: session, jboss, terracotta

I`m using JBoss 5.1.0 GA with Terracotta EHcache(with Hibernate). This setup works fine but when I try to add Terracotta WebSessions I get

```
09:28:11,894 ERROR [CoyoteAdapter] An exception or error occurred in the container during the request processing
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: callerSubject is null
        at org.jboss.security.plugins.javaee.WebAuthorizationHelper.hasRole(WebAuthorizationHelper.java:125)
        at org.jboss.web.tomcat.security.SecurityAssociationActions$10.run(SecurityAssociationActions.java:363)
        at org.jboss.web.tomcat.security.SecurityAssociationActions$10.run(SecurityAssociationActions.java:360)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at org.jboss.web.tomcat.security.SecurityAssociationActions.hasRole(SecurityAssociationActions.java:359)
        at org.jboss.web.tomcat.security.JBossWebRealm.hasRole(JBossWebRealm.java:598)
        at org.apache.catalina.realm.RealmBase.hasResourcePermission(RealmBase.java:789)
        at org.jboss.web.tomcat.security.JBossWebRealm.hasResourcePermission(JBossWebRealm.java:475)
        at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:507)
        at org.terracotta.modules.tomcat.tomcat_5_5.SessionValve55.tcInvoke(SessionValve55.java:99)
        at org.terracotta.modules.tomcat.tomcat_5_5.SessionValve55.invoke(SessionValve55.java:85)
        at org.terracotta.session.ModernTomcatSessionValve.invoke(ModernTomcatSessionValve.java:66)
        at org.jboss.web.tomcat.security.JaccContextValve.invoke(JaccContextValve.java:92)
        at org.jboss.web.tomcat.security.SecurityContextEstablishmentValve.process(SecurityContextEstablishmentValve.java:126)
        at org.jboss.web.tomcat.security.SecurityContextEstablishmentValve.invoke(SecurityContextEstablishmentValve.java:70)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:127)
        at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:102)
        at org.jboss.web.tomcat.service.jca.CachedConnectionValve.invoke(CachedConnectionValve.java:158)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:109)
        at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:330)
        at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.process(Http11Processor.java:829)
        at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11Protocol.java:598)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$Worker.run(JIoEndpoint.java:447)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:662)
```

I've followed the documentation on TC's website http://www.terracotta.org/documentation/product-documentation-1page.

I've also posted on their forum, on the dedicated WebSession section, but no one has answered :( .

If anyone has managed to configure a setup similar to mine please reply.

Thank you.